# How to create remote event receiver for EventReceiverType.GroupUserAddedevent in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, remote-event-receiver

I want to create remote event receiver which will trigger whenever any new user is added in SharePoint group.

That user details and group and site details I need to maintain in SQL Data base.

Regards
Rajat Sahani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GroupUserAdded in [SPRemoteEventType](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.remoteapp.spremoteeventtype?view=sharepoint-server)  to achieve this, check if the EventType is  `SPRemoteEventType.GroupUserAdded` .

Comment: Can I get any code repository for it?

Comment: Can I test it locally as I dont have Azure Subscription.

Comment: You can create a remote event receiver in SharePoint Add-ins : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-a-remote-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-add-ins

Comment: Can  you provide  sample GitHub repository for it